# What is AttributeError: object has no attribute 'w3c'?

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop, action

I am trying to perform drag and drop, python-webdriver.
But I'm not successful at it. Used simple drag and drop apis & drag and drop by offset. And also used action chains, nothing worked out for me. I could see few ppl mentioned that it has worked for them Could someone please guide me here.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

def test_drag_and_drop(self):
    source = self.find_elements("xpath=xpath_of_source")
    destination = self.find_elements("id=id_of_destination")  
    ActionChains(self).drag_and_drop(source, destination).perform()
    return(self)
```

Getting error : **AttributeError: object has no attribute 'w3c'?**

[image: Drag_and_Drop_Scenario]

```
Draggable part HTML Code:
<div id="textBox" class="whiteBox textBox" style="height:160px;width:100%;">
    <span style="padding-top:4px;padding-bottom:4px;clear:both;float:left;" _attr="constant" _type="textName">
        <div class="simpleClass" contenteditable="false" dontcancelselect="true" onselectstart="GetBrowser().allowDrag(event, this)" draggable="true">
          Text1
        <img class="textBox_icon" contenteditable="false" src="img/text_box.gif" style="display:none">
        </div>
   </span>
   <span> same for Text2 </span>
   <span> same for Text3 </span>

Droppable part HTML Code :
<div id="messageDiv" class="contentEditableOuterContainer multiLine" style="position:relative">
    <pre id="messagearea" class="contentEditableContainer multiLine inputpre" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">

Source : xpath=//div[@id='textBox']//div[contains(text(),'Text1')]
Destination : id=messagearea
```

**We can drag "Text1" to droppable area as many times.**

Comment: Can you share more details: how you created webdriver instance, how you use `test_drag_and_drop()` in your script, how `"xpath=xpath_of_source"` and `"id=id_of_destination"` looks in real code?

Comment: @Andersson: Let's say above function is in "test.py" (robot_page object), so even xpaths and ids are present in file. In my testcase file (filename.robot), i just call this function as "test_drag_and _drop". Of course, i open browser with robot keywords, "Open Browser".

Comment: @Andersson : Updated all the details above.

Comment: Please show the full error with stacktrace.